# Divide XML into specific nodes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

There is an XML string. I can't figure out how to get only the contents of the  node, and then split it into separate Persons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetJob xmlns="http:// ">
            <GetResult>
                <Result>00</Result>
                <Data>
                    <Person>
                        <Name>Ивано Иван Иванович</Name>
                        <Active>true</Active>
                    </Person>
                    <Person>
                        <Name>Петров Петр Петрович</Name>
                        <Active>true</Active>
                    </Person>
                </Data>
            </GetResult>
        </<GetJob >
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I tried something like

```
  XElement contacts = XElement.Parse();
contacts.Element(Element("GetJob ").Element("GetResult")
```

```html
            XElement contacts = XElement.Parse(
                @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://"">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetJob xmlns=""http:// "">
            <GetResult>
                <Result>00</Result>
                <Data>
                    <Person>
                        <Name>Ивано Иван Иванович</Name>
                        <Active>true</Active>
                    </Person>
                    <Person>
                        <Name>Петров Петр Петрович</Name>
                        <Active>true</Active>
                    </Person>
                </Data>
            </GetResult>
        </<GetJob >
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>");
            IEnumerable<XElement> de =
      from el in contacts.Descendants("soap")
      select el;
            foreach (XElement el in de)
                Console.WriteLine(el);
```

```
            XElement contacts = XElement.Parse(
                @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://"">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetJob xmlns=""http:// "">
            <GetResult>
                <Result>00</Result>
                <Data>
                    <Person>
                        <Name>Ивано Иван Иванович</Name>
                        <Active>true</Active>
                    </Person>
                    <Person>
                        <Name>Петров Петр Петрович</Name>
                        <Active>true</Active>
                    </Person>
                </Data>
            </GetResult>
        </<GetJob >
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>");
            IEnumerable<XElement> de =
      from el in contacts.Descendants("soap")
      select el;
            foreach (XElement el in de)
                Console.WriteLine(el);
```

Returns an error:"Name cannot begin with the '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3C. Line 18, position 11."  I tried it using the method of the Doctoral Candidates

Comment: `XName ns = "http://"; contacts.Descendants(ns + "Person")` etc

Comment: To be honest, not everyone understood what you mean.Can I go into more detail?

Comment: You can call `contacts.Descendants` to go down recursively https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.descendants?view=net-8.0#system-xml-linq-xcontainer-descendants(system-xml-linq-xname) You need to also use the default namespace, which has been added at the `GetJob` level

Comment: I tried your advice, but it didn't work out. I described the error in the question

Comment: You have an extra angle bracket in following line : </<GetJob >

Comment: Yes, I get an xml string in this form. And I need to break it down and get all the Person.There can be 100 or more of them.
Something in the likeness: 
                   <Person>
                        <Name>Петров Петр Петрович</Name>
                        <Active>true</Active>
                    </Person>

Comment: Fixed a typo, but the console returns empty

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution based on *LINQ to XML* API. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

All XML elements starting from `<GetJob xmlns='http://wow2'>`, and down below, are bound to the **default namespace**. So, we need to declare that namespace and use it in the expressions.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://wow'>
            <soap:Body>
                <GetJob xmlns='http://wow2'>
                    <GetResult>
                        <Result>00</Result>
                        <Data>
                            <Person>
                                <Name>Ивано Иван Иванович</Name>
                                <Active>true</Active>
                            </Person>
                            <Person>
                                <Name>Петров Петр Петрович</Name>
                                <Active>true</Active>
                            </Person>
                        </Data>
                    </GetResult>
                </GetJob>
            </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>");

    XNamespace ns2 = "http://wow2";

    var persons = xdoc.Descendants(ns2 + "Person")
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Name = x.Element(ns2  + "Name").Value,
            Active = x.Element(ns2 + "Active").Value
        }).ToList();
    
    Console.WriteLine(persons);
}
```

**Output**

| Name | Active |
| --- | --- |
| Ивано Иван Иванович | true |
| Петров Петр Петрович | true |

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for you.

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(xmlString);
var node = xml.GetElementsByTagName("GetResult")[0];

var ls = new List<Person>();
foreach (XmlNode n in node["Data"].GetElementsByTagName("Person"))
{
    ls.Add(new Person
    {
       Name =n["Name"].InnerXml,
       Active = n["Active"].InnerXml == "true" ? true : false
    });
}
```

Comment: Why use the archaic Xml Element library when Xml Linq is new and much better.

Comment: I wanted to clarify in var ls = new List<Person>(); What is Person? I get the error that there is no such variable.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to use Xml Linq.But I'm stuck somewhere. I will be grateful for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

    var personDetails = doc.Descendants()
    .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Person")
    .Select(x => new
    {
         Name = x.Elements().Where(i=> i.Name.LocalName == "Name").First().Value,
         Active = x.Elements().Where(i=> i.Name.LocalName == "Active").First().Value
    }).ToList();
```

or if you have only 2 Person properties

```
var personDetail = doc.Descendants()
    .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Person")
    .Select(x => new
    {
         Name = x.Elements().First().Value,
         Active = x.Elements().Last().Value 
    }).ToList();
```